# Connect/Disconnect Button

Tags: java

I am writing a pretty basic KnockKnock program for one of my classes. The class has been extremely vague with how to do a lot of the operations needed and I have zero experience with NetBeans. I have created my button to connect to the server.

```java
private void connectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        sock = new Socket(serverName.getText(), Integer.parseInt(portNumber.getText()));
        output.append("Server Conncetion Successful\n");
    } // end try
    catch (Exception ioe) {
        output.append("Connection Error\n");
        sock = null;
    }//end catch
```

The thing that I am struggling with is that once the connection is made, the connect button needs to change to say "disconnect" which then I would assume is where I need to put the code to close the socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea comes down to something like:

```
if socket is null then
    if create socket then
        change text of button to disconnect
    else 
        display error message
    endif
else
    close socket
    change text of button to connect
endif
```

Assuming you only have one button, it will always call the same action handler, so you need to change the logic based on if the `sock` is `null` or not, for example...

```
private void connectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (sock == null) {
        try {
            sock = new Socket(serverName.getText(), Integer.parseInt(portNumber.getText()));
            output.append("Server Conncetion Successful\n");
            connectDisconnectButton.setText("Disconnect");
        } // end try
        catch (Exception ioe) {
            output.append("Connection Error\n");
            sock = null;
        }//end catch
    } else {
        sock.close();
        sock = null;
        connectDisconnectButton.setText("Connect");
    }
}
```

*nb: Since all I have is an out of context snippet, I've "assumed" the name of the `JButton`*